# Generate random number in kernel module

Tags: linux, random, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Is there a rand() equivalent function in Linux that I can call in kernel space i.e. say from inside a kernel module ?

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/random-number-generator-inside-kernel-space-396313/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `get_random_bytes()` routine returns the requested number of random bytes and stores them in a buffer. This routine is for kernel modules that cannot be in a wait state.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/random-numbers-kernel-642087/

http://www.spinics.net/lists/newbies/msg00062.html